# Fragment Backstack Toolbar title

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, fragment-backstack

Is there an efficient way to automatically set the toolbar's title when adding/replacing fragments as well as popping fragments from the backstack?

I have implemented this abstract method in my `BaseFragment` class:

```
abstract fun header() : String

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    (activity as SSBaseActivity).header.text = header()
}
```

and I modify the `header` in each `Fragment` that inherits from my `BaseFragment`  class and displays the value in `onResume` but I noticed that when I press back, the last title set isn't being replaced from the fragment currently in the stack.

Comment: You can add tags to a fragment and in onBackStackChangedListener you can switch the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this by using an [`OnBackStackChangedListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener) in your `Activity`:

```
supportFragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener {
    val fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.yourFragmentFrame)
    if (fragment is BaseFragment) {
        header.text = fragment.header()
    }
}
```